# UDP socket and multiple replies

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I'm a learner, so please be patient and clear. I am writing an echo client with Java sockets (DatagramSocket).

After the client sends a message to the echo server, the server deliberately sends 1-10 copies of the message back to simulate message duplication in UDP.

However, my code can only receive the first of those messages sent back, never the full number sent by the server. My receive code is like this:

```
socket.receive(receivePacket);
```

How would I put my client in a state where you can enter a string to echo, say "Hi", it is then sent to the server, but can then receive all the replies? I am assuming that they all make it back to the client (I am testing this on my local machine so there will be no loss)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call socket.receive again to receive additional packets.  [Set a timeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29) to wait a reasonable amount of time before deciding the server has sent all its packets.

Comment: Hi... so I would first set the socket timeout to say 1000ms, then send a message via that socket, then say enter a while(true) loop that calls socket.receive(...) until a SocketTimeoutException is thrown... this would be the "maximum time window" to allow replies to reach the client. Does that sound sane?

Comment: Yes.  You may consider setting the timeout after you send the initial message. I'd suggest waiting perhaps up to 3-5 seconds for the first response (especially if you are doing this over the internet), then change the timeout back to 1 seconds to consume the duplicates.